# OS X Yosemite upgrade: Game not recognized by Game Center

Tags: c++, macos, game-center

Yesterday I upgraded OS X to **Yosemite**, and since then my game is not recognised by Game Center. **GKErrorDomain**: code 15 and the text:

**"The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognised by Game Center."**

I've checked Developer -> Use Sandbox Server in the Game Center App without results. Also, tried Clean, Build again. It seems the GC App not enters sandbox mode?

As I said the game worked fine until I upgraded to Yosemite.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Have you resolved it already?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Any news on this issue? I'm struggling it too for more than a week now.

Comment: No news :-( Even when the game is live on the app store it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that OS X Yosemite has new functions that the game cannot support, since the game was made for an older version of OS. You might have to upgrade everything and see if it works. If not, then you should ask the question on the apple web page.
[ask questions about osx yosemite here(go to the support, and then go to the osx)](http://apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to fix the issue. This is not about new functions. I do not see why the GC is not changing to sandbox mode and not showing the sandbox mode itself.

The failure is coming from GC as it tries to locate the running game in the production server, but it should try to find it in the Sandbox server, where it is set up.

Sometimes when you run a new version of your game using still the old version numbers, you can test the product on the production server as well. But in my case this is a new app with a new ID, so I cannot do that. I would need the Sandbox server, but it doe snot show up at all.

I am thinking about going back to Mavericks and check it there.

Actually I have checked what the software tries to reach. It is actually the production server of the game center, so it is not the right one for sure, but I cannot figure out how can I force OS X to use the sandbox server when tries to login to the Game Center.